# Warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: Unable to access / Plesk issue

Tags: linux, plesk

I've just upgraded my server to version 9.3 of plesk from parallels.  Now all my joomla sites ( and others) are showing a

> Warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: Unable to access / "file
>   location"  error.

Any ideas what I can do to resolve it??

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem  with Joomla.  I fixed it by turning off safe mod in `php.ini`.